# Azure build include implicit project dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have solution with Azure WorkerRole and a few more projects that I use via Reflection (no explicit reference). How can I include those projects in Azure package (build projects automatically and have it in Azure package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the best article about the problem I found so far:

https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/azure-service-packages-with-unreferenced-assemblies/